# SequelizeJS: Wrong order of Column Values when using Numbers as String

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new to SequelizeJS and using it for PostgreSQL with NodeJS application.

I have a table:

```
sequelize.define('log', {
    id: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    statusCode: type.INTEGER,
    status: type.STRING,
    message: type.TEXT,
    lastRecordId: type.STRING,
    lastRecordTime: type.DATE
});
```

The problem is that, when I run a query for fetching the values from `lastRecordId` column in `DESC` order, I get wrong order of the values:

[image: Wrong order of values]

I did not want to use `INTEGER` nor `BIGINT` on that column, because it contains a code not a real number.

The query I am using is:

```
        LoggerModel
            .findAll({
                order: [ [ 'lastRecordId', 'DESC' ]],
            })
            .then( allLogs => {
                //...
            })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have  found a solution by using the answers of @bereket and from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212187/sequelize-cast-column-to-integer-in-where-clause).
What worked for me is as follows:

```
    LoggModel
        .findAll({
            order: [
                [ sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('lastRecordId'), 'BIGINT') , 'DESC' ]
            ]
        })
        .then((logs) => { /// })
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it on the fly without changing the column to type. Then you can order on with that.

```
LoggerModel
        .findAll({
            order: [
                     sequelize.cast('lastRecordId', 'BIGINT'),
                     [ 'lastRecordId', 'DESC' ]
              ],
        })
        .then( allLogs => {
            //...
        })
```

[inspired by this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2063)

Comment: It's generating `invalid input syntax for integer: "log.lastRecordId"`. Any idea about...???

Comment: My table name is Log and I am using `log` as table name in model definition.

Comment: Ok, try just with 'lastRecordId', I hv updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have tried with `lastRecordId` but failed to get the results. Also, I have used `log.lastRecordId` without any luck. Same database error is occurring.